# Sorting a Gridview using Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, datatable

I have a gridview which I want to sort when any of its column header is clicked. There is a DataTable that is built on runtime and assigned to the gridview to populate data. Here is the DataTable and Gridview:

```
DataTable dtMedication = new DataTable();
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Id");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("BrandName");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("GenericName");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Dosage");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Physician");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("DatePrescribed");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Status");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("ClientMedicationDataId");

<asp:GridView ID="gdvMainList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            SkinID="PagedGridView" onrowcommand="gdvMainList_RowCommand" 
                            DataKeyNames="Id" onsorting="gdvMainList_Sorting">
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="gridpager" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <Columns>
                                <ucc:CommandFieldControl HeaderText="Actions" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image"
                                    DeleteImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/delete.png" ShowEditButton="true"
                                    EditImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/edit.png" DeleteConfirmationText="Are you sure you want to delete?">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="60px" />
                                </ucc:CommandFieldControl>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BrandName" HeaderText="Brand Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="GenericName" HeaderText="Generic Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Dosage" HeaderText="Dosage" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Physician" HeaderText="Physician" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DatePrescribed" HeaderText="Date Prescribed" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="HiddenCol" Width="0px" />
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HiddenCol" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfClientMedicationDataId" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("ClientMedicationDataId") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <div class="divEmptyGrid">
                                    --- No Medication Exists ---
                                </div>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: what seems to the problem in doing so? what do you have in gdvMainList_Sorting?

Comment: I haven't written anything in that event handler yet. Problem is I dnt know how to handle that event according to my grid and datatable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First step to set `AllowSorting` property of `GridView` to `true` then add `SortExpression` property for each column you would to use for sorting:

> SortExpression property indicates the expression that should be
>   used to sort the data when that field's sorting header link is clicked

Let's consider `BoundField` from your code above, I have added a `SortExpression` property with value set to `BrandName` which means that when the column header for `BrandName` will be clicked column 'BrandName' in your `DataTable` will be used to sort the data:

Now in `gdvMainList_Sorting` event you have to rebind the grid to sorted data:

```
protected void gdvMainList_Sorting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //Using DataView for sorting DataTable's data
    DataView view = dtMedication.DefaultView;
    view.Sort = String.Format("{0} {1}", e.SortExpression, GetSortingDirection());
    gdvMainList.DataSource = view;
    gdvMainList.DataBind();
}
```

If you have noticed I have used getSortingDirection(), which a method that returns either 'ASC' or 'DESC' for sorting data in either ascending or descending order, respectively.

```
protected string GetSortingDirection() 
{
    if(ViewState["SortDirection"] == null)
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
    else if(ViewState["SortDirection"] == "ASC")
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "DESC";
    else
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";

    return ViewState["SortDirection"];
}
```

Some useful links:

1. [GridView sorting using VB.net](http://www.vbnettutorial.net/?Id=120&Desc=GridView-Sorting-Vb.Net)
2. [Sorting and Paging tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404876.aspx#aspnett24pagsortrdcs_topic10)

Comment: One snippit of code I added in the sorting event handler was if(viewState["SortColumn"] <> e.SortExpressions) ViewState["sortDirection"] = null; ViewState["SortColumn"] = e.SortExpression; This defaults back to ASC when you click on a different column

Answer (score 0):

For sorting the rows of the grid view you should use the SortDescription class constructor  and passing two arguments to this class namely, sortby value and also the direction of sorting. Refer to the [Sort gridrows based on column click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786.aspx) for more details.